# Sort values in single row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to know how to sort values in a single row in MySQL.

For example if am having a row like ID, Height, Weight, Rank, Score and sample values are: 1,162,52,2,42.

Can we write a query and get it sorted like 1,2,42,52,162?

The ID, Height, Weight, Rank, Score are field names only. I feel this is impossible but if there is a work-around to achieve this please let me know.

//structure

```
CREATE TABLE `properties` (
  `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `Weight` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `Height` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rank` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Score` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: Can you post the schema? It is possible.

Comment: @ChristianMark I was just curious thinking about this feature that is why I was asking, Just consider a normal table I gave in the example with few fields. You told it is possible right, can you tell me how?

Comment: Do you fetch only one record?

Comment: @ChristianMark because I thought only columns could be sorted and not rows.

Comment: It can be done using huge CASE statements. It's not clear for what reason do you need it. Also in two different rows the order can be different so you will lose information about field names.

Comment: It can be multiple records

Comment: If it is multiple records and if I do not know the order how the values would be in how will I sort it can you give me an example? @ChristianMark

Comment: @user2409375 as valex said you can achieve it by using case statement. Similarly can be used with if but it will be very clumsy.

Comment: like one value can be this 1,162,52,2,42. Then another can be 2,255,155,3,1 and so on. How would I sort the row automatically while fetching the values? I hope you understood what I am trying to convey here.@ChristianMark

Comment: Can someone give me an example for this?

Comment: Why are you guys down voting this question? It is just a genuine doubt

Comment: @user2409375, Im not a downvoter but what you try to achieve actually is meaningless. SQL is based on the relational model of data. One of the principles of the relational model is that the order of columns is meaningless. I said that it can be achieve through a multiple case in a stored procedure. If you really want this, you might want to consider doing it on your front-end (like PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT   if (
        height <
           if (
              Weight <
                 if (Score < if (ID < RANK, ID, RANK),
                     Score,
                     if (ID < RANK, ID, RANK)),
              weight,
              if (Score < if (ID < RANK, ID, RANK),
                  Score,
                  if (ID < RANK, ID, RANK))
           ),
        height,
        if (
           Weight <
              if (Score < if (ID < RANK, ID, RANK),
                  Score,
                  if (ID < RANK, ID, RANK)),
           weight,
           if (Score < if (ID < RANK, ID, RANK),
               Score,
               if (ID < RANK, ID, RANK))
        )
     ),
     if (
        height >
           if (
              Weight >
                 if (Score > if (ID > RANK, ID, RANK),
                     Score,
                     if (ID > RANK, ID, RANK)),
              weight,
              if (Score > if (ID > RANK, ID, RANK),
                  Score,
                  if (ID > RANK, ID, RANK))
           ),
        height,
        if (
           Weight >
              if (Score > if (ID > RANK, ID, RANK),
                  Score,
                  if (ID > RANK, ID, RANK)),
           weight,
           if (Score > if (ID > RANK, ID, RANK),
               Score,
               if (ID > RANK, ID, RANK))
        )
     )
  FROM   properties;
```

It will only give you 1st(minimum value) and last(maximum value). Similarly you can achieve middle values, which is obviously a clumsy work. Anyways i don't know if it can achieve in PHP(or an other language) easily or not.

Comment: The question now here is how to identify the 2nd and 3rd. Sounds challenging.